# GNU GRUB purple Screen

Tags: 12.04, grub2, screen

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 about two weeks ago and everything booted fine and dandy. About four days ago I booted my laptop and instead of the usual it came up with this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/img0076sd.jpg/

[image]

I installed Ubuntu after Windows 8 caused havoc with my machine (no physical damage) and as such I installed Ubuntu on it's own (no Wubi). Selecting any of the options seems to do nothing (the first option just leaves me with a blinking cursor).

I'm not someone who's competent with coding so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried selecting the `Previous versions` option

Answer (score 2):

Try Boot Repair.

### 1 - Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### 2 - Repair the bootloader

To repair and restore the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open a terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running now.

Comment: @John No problem! Please mark the answer as accepted, to prevent it from showing up in the *Unanswered* section. Thank you! :)